# I need to pass textbox name into AngularS routing page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-routing

I have on login page with AngularJS Routing, Which contains name and password. After i put correct name and password this will go to another html by routing. Here i need to show the name which i type in the login page -> name field. Is this possible? My code below.,

```
<body ng-controller="loginCtrl">
<form class="col-sm-6" action="EmployeeDetails.asmx/getLoginDetails" method="get" id="empForm" name="empForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="EmpName" name="EmpName" class="form-control" ng-model="empname" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ng-required="true" />
        <span ng-show="empForm.EmpName.$touched && empForm.EmpName.$error.required" class="error">Please enter your name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id">Employee ID: </label>
        <input type="text" id="empId" class="form-control" ng-model="empid" name="empID" placeholder="Enter Your ID" ng-required="true" />
        <span ng-show="empForm.empID.$touched && empForm.empID.$error.required" class="error">Please enter your ID</span>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" />Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="empForm.$valid" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="empSubmit()" />
</form>
```

**Script**

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/Login", {
    templateUrl: "/Calc_Sys/Login.html",
    controller:'loginCtrl'
}).when('/LogOut', {
    templateUrl: "/Calc_Sys/LogOut.html",
    controller: 'logoutCtrl'
}).when('/Calculator', {
    templateUrl: "/Calc_Sys/Calculator.html",
    controller: 'calcCtrl'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/Login"
})
```

**Calculator.html**

```
<body ng-controller="calcCtrl">
    Wellcome {{EmpName}} !!!
 </body>
```

Here i need to show the **EmpName**.

Comment: You should look for using `resolve` in the angular router

Comment: if possible please share code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.when('/Calculator/:empname', {
    templateUrl: "/Calc_Sys/Calculator.html",
    controller: 'calcCtrl'
})

Controller
----------------
Use $routeParams
Get the value $routeParams.empname

Assign value $scope.EmpName=$routeParams.empname
```

$routeParams.empname which means what  text in anchor tag href. It is dynamic.

Comment: $routeParams.empname which means what i type in anchor tag href, but i need what i type in text box. It is dynamic.